# Align TabLayout with collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a collapsing toolbar and a tablayout in my layout file.
The tab layout only appears when the toolbar is fully collapsed.
My problem is, the tab layout appears like this:

[image]

But I want it to show completely, something like this:

[image]

I tried to change the *gravity* and the *anchor* (as it is wrapped up in a *Coordinator layout*) but I don't seem to be able to make it happen.
This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relLayoutCountryInfo"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparainfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarDivider">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbarinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCountryInfoFoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCountryInfoEscuro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_pais_info"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEscuroCountryTopo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleX="2"
            android:scaleY="-1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blur_paises_filtro" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbaridinfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
            android:id="@+id/blurView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:realtimeBlurRadius="10dp"
            app:realtimeOverlayColor="#8000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNomePaisInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/txtNomeContinente"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtContinenteNome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparainfo"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVoltar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_back_branca" />

        <com.like.LikeButton
            android:id="@+id/heart_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="340dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            app:icon_size="25dp"
            app:icon_type="heart"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/txtNomeContinente"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom">

        </com.like.LikeButton>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/includeTeste"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left" />
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/includeTeste"
    layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />
```

Comment: Provide hieght to appbarlayout and collapsingtoolbar to wrap content

Comment: That does not help because I need it to be match_parent